# Docusign XML Check as Checkbox

Tags: docusignapi

I’m trying to populate a checkbox on a template.

The documentation at https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Tab.htm tell me to set Value = “X” to check the checkbox.   That doesn’t work.

Now I found documentation at https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Checkbox%20Tab.htm that tells me to set select = true

How do you check a checkbox?

Here’s a summary of the XML:

```
    <envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <status>sent</status>
  <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Embedded Signing example</emailSubject>
  <templateId>GUID TEMPLATE ID</templateId>
  <templateRoles>
    <templateRole>
      <email>NAME1@DOMAIN.COM</email>
      <name>First Last</name>
      <roleName>Applicant</roleName>
      <clientUserId>CLIENTUSERID1</clientUserId>
      <tabs>
        <textTabs>
          <text>
            <tabLabel>ApplicationNumber</tabLabel>
            <value>APPLICATIONNUMBER</value>
          </text>
          <text>
            <tabLabel>checkBoxLabel1</tabLabel>
            <selected>true</selected>
          </text>
          <text>
            <tabLabel>checkBoxLabel2</tabLabel>
            <value>X</value>
          </text>
        </textTabs>
      </tabs>
    </templateRole>
    <templateRole>
      <email>NAME2@DOMAIN.COM</email>
      <name>FIRSTNAME LASTNAME</name>
      <roleName>Producer</roleName>
      <clientUserId>CLIENTUSERID2</clientUserId>
    </templateRole>
  </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the documentation differs, I'll submit a docs request with DocuSign

Comment: By the way, have you seen the restapi help page located here?  https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help That will help you in constructing properly formatted XML requests...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check box is not a `textTab` (which translates to a data field in the Console UI).  To specify a checkbox in the xml format try this:

```
<tabs>
    <textTabs>
        <text>
            <tabLabel>ApplicationNumber</tabLabel>
            <value>APPLICATIONNUMBER</value>
        </text>
    </textTabs>
    <checkboxTabs>
        <checkbox>
            <selected>true</selected>
            <shared>false</shared>
            <tabLabel>checkBoxLabel1</tabLabel>             
        </checkbox>
    <checkbox>
```