# Setting the value of a checkbox in a template via the DocuSign e-sign API

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

In my project I'm using a Laravel wrapper of the [DocuSign PHP Client Library](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/) to interact with the e-sign REST API, in order to pre-populate fields in a DocuSign template.

The text tabs make sense as you pass through a minimum of two keys in an array to set values:

```
'textTabs' => [
    [
        'tabLabel' => '[DATA_LABEL]',
        'value' => $this->model_attribute,
    ],
]
```

However, check boxes have caught me at a loss because I tried the exact same thing, but with boolean values:

```
'checkboxTab' => [
    [
        'tabLabel' => '[DATA_LABEL]',
        'value' => $this->model_attribute_thats_a_boolean, // true or false
    ],
]
```

When reviewing my document the check boxes were not ticked, irrespective of the value, so I did some digging in the base PHP client library.

This is a link to the underlying class for a checkboxTab:

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Model/Checkbox.php

On line `1945` there is this setter:

```
/**
 * Sets selected
 * @param string $selected When set to **true**, the checkbox is selected.
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSelected($selected)
{
    $this->container['selected'] = $selected;

    return $this;
}
```

Given this, I came to the assumption that you shouldn't actually pass `value` as a key, but instead `selected`, so I tried this:

```
'checkboxTab' => [
    [
        'tabLabel' => '[DATA_LABEL]',
        'selected' => $this->model_attribute_thats_a_boolean, // true or false
    ],
]
```

However, even this did not check the corresponding checkboxes within the document, so I'm a little perplexed.

Even [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660563/docusign-xml-check-as-checkbox?rq=1) seems to suggest I'm along the correct lines.

Comment: Are you really supposed to just pass plain data arrays? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53797445/1427878 appears to be explicitly creating new instances of the corresponding model classes, like `$check1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Checkbox(['tab_label' => 'ckAuthorization', 'selected' => "true"]);`, maybe that’s what you need to do here as well?

Comment: Potentially, I was basing it on the fact that the fields already exist within a template with a given data label. I'll try this though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue is it should be a string for true/false, not a boolean. You can do this:

```
'checkboxTab' => [
    [
        'tabLabel' => '[DATA_LABEL]',
        'selected' => $this->model_attribute_thats_a_boolean ? 'true' : 'false'
    ],
]
```